# Blip.TV i want the video start muted

Tags: javascript, video, flash, mute

I have this code:

```
<iframe src="http://blip.tv/play/h7wFArSqTA.html" width="760" height="500" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe><embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="http://a.blip.tv/api.swf#h7wFArSqTA" style="display:none"></embed>
```

But what can i do to get it muted at start, is it even possible to mute frames?

And how can i use this code:

```
var player = document.getElementById("stratos_embed");
player.sendEvent("mute"); // set the volume to 100%
```

Comment: You can't mute a frame. Where is that code from? Does it have something to do with blip.tv?

Comment: Well yes, it have something to do with blip.tv

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to have the video start up muted, however, I'm having issues figuring it out myself. http://wiki.blip.tv/index.php/Showplayer#Available_Parameters